# Python Dataframe Panda - Computing weighted sum if condition matches and group results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compute a weighted sum based on a condition on the `criteria` column. 
I have the following Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'criteria': [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9], 
                   'weight': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 
                   'value': [0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]})
print(df)

   criteria  weight  value
0         2       1    0.2
1         2       2    0.6
2         2       3    0.1
3         3       1    0.9
4         4       2    0.8
5         5       1    0.7
6         5       2    0.3
7         9       3    0.8
```

The possible values of the `weight` column are {1, 2, 3}.

I would like to compute the weighted sum `df['weight'] * df['value']` if and only if there is a row for all the possible `weights` and the same `criteria` value, and then group them by `criteria` values. The rest would be `NaN`.

In my example, only the rows with `df['criteria'] == 2` fill this condition.

So we would have:

```
   criteria  weighted_sum
0         2           1.7
1         3           NaN
2         4           NaN
3         5           NaN
4         9           NaN
```

How to write this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `issubset` to check if the weights is a subset of the group and then take a sum using `series.where`:

```
weights = [1,2,3]
cond = df.groupby('criteria')['weight'].agg(lambda x: set(weights).issubset(set(x)))
(df['weight'].mul(df['value']).groupby(df['criteria']).sum()
                     .where(cond).reset_index(name='weighted_sum'))
```

---

```
   criteria  weighted_sum
0         2           1.7
1         3           NaN
2         4           NaN
3         5           NaN
4         9           NaN
```